# what does this property in ant's build.xml mean?

Tags: java, ant

In a project's build.xml there is a properity

```
<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.7"/>
```

it is not used in other places in the build.xml, but if i modify it's value to 1.6, i will

get an error.

what does this properity mean?

i am in China, Google has been blocked here.....

Comment: Folks are pretty quick to downvote; IMO this is a legitimate question, light on details.

Comment: This is a fairly simple thing to Google.

Comment: @DaveNewton someone downvoted before cyberrusher added the code for the property, it happened real quick

Comment: @linski It was there, it wasn't escaped so it was invisible.

Comment: IMO closing as "too localized" is completely wrong; there's nothing localized about the question. Closing as poorly-researched, perhaps, but hardly localized.

Comment: -1: Trivial and quicker to Google than to post a question.

Comment: unfortunately, i am in China. Google is blocked by the government, because the government do not want the people to see anything that is not good for the Communist Party. So, please do not be so harsh，my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ant.apache.org/manual/javacprops.html

They define values for the `javac` (and `javadoc`) task since there are no default values.

This can cause problems in some circumstances, so magic properties were defined.

If you're trying to compile 1.7 source using a 1.6 compiler you'll have issues if you're using 1.7 constructs/etc.

Answer (score 1):

The value determines what version of the JDK is used to build the project.  You probably get an error on 1.6 because it's not installed/doesn't support something you use in your project.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/javacprops.html